# Como devolver una lista a un controlador por post

Tags: c#, mvc

Cargo mi lista por get una lista de personas y la cargo en una tabla html pero luego tengo que devolver la misma lista por post pero me la retorna vacía

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GestionUsuarios(string f)
    {
        Response res = new Response();
        DataMorce<Usuario> bdUsuario = new DataMorce<Usuario>();
        DataMorce<Archivo> bdArchivos = new DataMorce<Archivo>();
        GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionView = new GestionUsuariosViewModel();

        if (HttpContext.Session["Idusers"] == null || HttpContext.Session["users"] == null)
        {
            LevantarSesiones(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        }
        int idInstitucion = (int)Session["IdInstitucion"];
        int idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(Session["users"]);

        List<Persona> listaPer = bdInstitucion.GetFilter(x => x.IdInstitucion == idInstitucion).SelectMany(p => p.Personas).OrderBy(x => x.Nombres).ToList();

        var listaPersonas = new List<Personas>();
        listaPersonas = listaPer;


        gestionView.ListaPersonas = listaPersonas;
        return View(gestionView);
    }
```

y luego por post me devuelve la misma lista vacía

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GestionUsuarios(List<Persona> listaPersonas, GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionView)
    {
        GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionUserView = new GestionUsuariosViewModel();
        List<Persona> listaPers= new List<Persona>();
        Response res = new Response();
        DataMorce<Usuario> bdUsuario = new DataMorce<Usuario>();

        int idInstitucion = (int)Session["idinstitucion"];
        int idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(Session["users"]);

        var l = ViewBag.Model;
        //
        return View(listaPersonas);
    }
```

La vista html

```html
@model WEBMORCE.Model.GestionUsuariosView.GestionUsuariosViewModel @{ ViewBag.Title = "Gestión de Usuario"; }
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>GestionUsuarios</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row col-md-12">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GestionUsuarios", "GestionUsuarios", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                                    {
                                        <input type="submit" value="Generar usuarios" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
                                    }
    <table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="8" data-filter=#filter>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" id="checkTodos" class="i-checks" name="input[]"></th>
          <th>Nombre </th>
          <th>Usuario </th>
          <th>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ListaPersonas) {
        <tr class="gradeA">
          <td class="col-md-1">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked, new { idPersona = item.IdPersona, @class = "i-checks" })
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="pull-left">
              <div class="text-center">
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlFoto)) {
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.UrlFoto)" alt="Perfil" class="zoom img-circle" style="height:30px; width:30px" /> }
              </div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreCompleto)
          </td>
          <td>
            @if (item.NombreUser == "Sin Usuario") {
            <span class="badge text-bold bg-danger" title="Sin usuario">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> } else {
            <span class="badge text-bold bg-primary" title="Usuario activo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> }
            <span class="pie">
                                                                    @item.NombreUser
                                                                </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle">Opciones <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href='@Url.Action("InformacionParticipante", "Estudiantes", new { idPersona = item.IdPersona })'>Editar Información</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Actividad/Auditoria *</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Restablecer clave *</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recordar clave *</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        } @*@Html.ActionLink("Listados", "GestionUsuarios", new { listaPersona = Model.ListaPersonas})*@
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola Juan puedes adjuntar los documentos de HTML (Vista), eso nos ayudará más, dado que nos mostrará más información de ¿Cómo llamas el controlador Post: GestionUsuarios.

Comment: Gracias @diegoorellana acabo de agregar la vista html y el controlador si se llama "GestionUsuarios" de ante mano gracias

Comment: Gracias por la vista, una pregunta más.. en la sección @foreach si te imprime  persona (En otras palabras: ¿a la hora de hacer el GET, obtienes la lista?).

Comment: Si en el Get si devuelve la lista normal y los imprime en la tabla bien

Comment: Gracias, trata de borrar el parametro **GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionView** de la función POST: GestionUsuarios. (Me cuentas si te dio resultado).

Comment: Devuelve la lista null, Gracias

Comment: Mmm, estaba mirando más a detalle el código, y veo que retornas la misma vista, lo cual dicha vista tiene como modelo: **GestionUsuariosViewModel**, por lo tanto te recomiendo tener solo el parametro **GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionView** en la función Post, y eliminar el parámetro de lista, y en la misma función retornar el objeto gestionView: **return View(gestionView)**.

Comment: Así mismo en la vista te recomiendo colocar lo siguiente: @*@Html.ActionLink("Listados", "GestionUsuarios", new { gestionView = Model})*@ y te debe funcionar... Me cuenta tus resultados

Comment: Compañero nada, la lista me sigue devolviendo null

Comment: Una pregunta, que funcionalidad tendrá: GestionUsuarios (Post)?

Comment: Generar un usuario para loguearse, este usuario se le va a generar a la persona que tenga el checkbox de la primera columna seleccionado, por eso voy a pasar la misma lista que imprimo en el GET por que tiene un campo que toma el valor del checkbox, y si esta seleccionado pues le genero usuario y si no pues no pasa nada, pero este se puede generar para una persona o en su defecto para todos los de la lista. Gracias

Comment: Entendió compañero?

Comment: Puedes inspeccionar el post request y colocar acá la información generada, para ver que y como está enviando la información el post

Comment: Ya lo resolví, cambie los controles razor por controles nativos html y el foreach con el cual llenaba la tabla los cambie por un for el cambiolo hice solamente en la vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que tuve fue cambiar los controles razor que tenia por controles nativos de html

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  @*@Html.Action("GridView3Partial", "GestionUsuarios")*@

  <form method="post" action="/GestionUsuarios/GestionUsuarios">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="datos" data-page-size="8" data-filter=#filter>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre </th>
          <th>Usuario </th>
          <th>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ListaPersonas) {
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="pull-left">
              <div class="text-center">
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.UrlFoto)) {
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.UrlFoto)" alt="Perfil" class="zoom img-circle" style="height:30px; width:30px" /> }
              </div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreCompleto)
          </td>
          <td>
            @if (item.NombreUser == "Sin Usuario") {
            <span class="badge text-bold bg-danger" title="Sin usuario">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> } else {
            <span class="badge text-bold bg-primary" title="Usuario activo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> }
            <span class="pie">
                                                                    @item.NombreUser
                                                                </span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle">Opciones <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                @*
                <li><a href='@Url.Action("InformacionParticipante", "Estudiantes", new { idPersona = item.IdPersona })'>Editar Información</a></li>*@
                <li><a href="#">Editar Información</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Restablecer clave</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recordar clave</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Asignar Institución</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podias poner el codigo HTML que se genera?

Cuando yo he tenido que hacer algo similar, me ha funcionado con:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GestionUsuarios(List<string> listaPersonas, GestionUsuariosViewModel gestionView)
    {
    }
```

El HTML que genera tu vista debe de ser del estilo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="listaPersonas" value="loquesea">
```

El value del checkbox puedes leerlo como un string.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos